# Embedding & Running a HTML File on a Wordpress Website

Tags: html, wordpress, twine-game-engine

I have developed a text-based computer game (with Twine) - this is output as an HTML file. I would like to embed this file on a wordpress website so that it can be played regularly.
There is a wordpress plugin (Embed Twine) that makes this possible, but it doesn't always work reliably.
What other possibilities are there?
Thank you!

- Tried iFrames solutions / does not work, as usually only a URL and not a whole HTML file can be embedded.
- Tried Embed Twine as a Wordpress plugin / very unreliable

Comment: I'm not familiar with Twine but why wouldn't iframes work? Couldn't you just put the HTML file to your `wp-content` directory and use its URL?

Comment: Thank's alot! It worked with wp-content. Now I have the problem that the source code of the html file can easily be accessed. Is there a possibility to encode the html file in a way that the intellectual property is at least somehow protected?